Interpretation of tolerances for a microchip's leads (position and profile)
In this diagram, taken from a JEDEC microchip drawing (https://www.jedec.org/standards-documents/docs/ms-012f - requires free registration). It is drawn per ASME Y14.5M-1994.
[
With datum C being the seating plane:
[
The overall width across the pins is a basic dimension of 6.00mm, and the distance from the center to the lead end is also basic, 3.00mm.
The planarity of the lead end surfaces is controlled by a profile tolerance bbb (given separately in a table as 0.20mm), repeated N/2 times, for each pair of opposed leads (N is the pin count). The profile tolerance is in a feature control frame on the extension line of the basic dimension 6.00mm. So it seems to be controlling the lead end surface, but I'm not sure how being referenced to the C datum works in this case. And it's not clear to me if how the profile is "split" between the two ends of the two opposed leads.
The location of the lead feature has a MMC location tolerance of ddd (0.25mm). And the FCF is attached to the dimension of the lead feature (NX b), so it's controlling each of the N features of size (the leads).
My question is, given these dimensions and tolerances, how the position and profile tolerances are supposed to be combined to give an overall description of the allowable positions of the leads.
In particular, I'm not clear on the maximum/minimum allowable values of the overall width of the part (i.e. the 6.00mm basic dimension).
For example, am I supposed to consider that each pin can independently "deviate" from the ideal position by up to 0.125mm in X and/or Y (so within a 0.25x0.25mm square), but with the additional restriction that all parts of the end surface remain within a profile zone 0.2mm wide centered around the ideal end surface (i.e. restricting to 0.1mm in Y)?

Reading mechanical drawings is not my forte, but for the electronics part of the question consider that each leg is crafted individually and attached to bonding wires internally. So it would make sense if tolerances are specified per individual leg. And then of course when the part is soldered, capillary action moves it a lot in all 3 dimensions within the "land pattern". So depending on why you need to know these measurements, you may or may not need way bigger tolerances than 0.20mm.

@Lundin, yes, sure. I'm mostly curious as to the correct interpretation of the tolerances in this case as I don't understand the combination. In practice the actual maximum dimensions are usually found in min/max form in a manufacturer datasheet: these are the values you really need for, say, IPC land pattern calculations (which include tolerance allowances and defined toe, heel and side fillets which control self-centering). Also, FYI, legs are not made individually - they are part of a single "leadframe", at least until the dambars are trimmed, which is after encapsulation.

It sounds to me like the top-to-bottom "length" of the pins must be 6.00mm ±  bbb mm, and the offset of the pins from the main package (a shift, not length increase/decrease) can be ± ddd mm.   These appear to be intentionally decoupled - for example the PCB board it attaches to likely requires the "length" spec to match the solder prints etc., and is determined by the "leadframe" as you said, whereas the PCB board may be fairly agnostic to package offset which really only affects the leg lengths.
I think you are asking to convert that length & offset into a min/max for how much the legs "stick out of the package".  If so, I think you'd do the following:
Find the Min by:

take the max allowed shift upwards (+ddd millimeters)
apply the minimum total length on one side: 6.00 - bbb/2 mm
maybe also add the tolerance for the package size: maximum allowed package size expansion. (not shown in the screenshot)
This should give you the minimum allowed length of a leg extending out of the package side.

Then do a similar exercise (effectively reversing the signs above) to get the "max" leg length w/r/to the side of the package.
Let me know if I'm understanding your question correctly here.
